# Hash password before sending to server over HTTPS?

Tags: java, android, api, rest, hash

When sending a password from my Android app to my web server's REST API (over HTTPS), should I hash the password?

In my database, the user's password is stored as a bcrypt hash. How (and should I?) can I bcrypt hash a password in Java?

Thanks.